# iPad app crashes on receiving multiple notifications

Tags: xcode, debugging, instruments, nszombie

I have an iPad app in which users can share images and receive notifications. When the user sure something twice simultaneously with another user, the receiver gets two notifications, each one regarding the share. It then asks if it has to ignore or load the shared image. In case I ignore the first notification and click on load in second notification, my app crashes.

I want to debug this by enabling zombies but notifications are not received on simulator. I have o test it on device only. Is there any way where in I can enable zombies on my device and test it? Can anyone suggest me a better approach to test an app running on device. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to test on your device with zombies on, enable zombies by editing your build scheme, plug in your device, build and run on the device in debug mode and you'll be good to go.

Comment: How do I edit my build scheme to enable zombies ?

Comment: Answer below - need to do that to get images in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Zombies select the scheme for your device in Xcode with the toolbar with the dropdown box above where it says "Scheme". Then click "Edit Scheme..."

[image: Scheme Editor Dropdown]

In the sheet that pops down, select the "Diagnostics" item, and "Enable Zombie Objects".

[image: Edit scheme sheet]

Then when you build and run that scheme Zombies will be enabled.